# Add class to element based on body id

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying add a class to a particular list element based on the id of the body but am not sure how to do so.

Here's what I have so far:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var navbar = "<div class='nav'><ul class='nav'>{{#each links}}<li><a href='#{{link}}'>{{name}}</a></li>{{/each}}</ul></div>"
    template_nav = Handlebars.compile(navbar);
    var navlinks = [{link:"home", name:"Home"},{link:"about", name:"About Us"}, {link:"contact", name:"Contact Us"}];

    document.querySelector("#nav").innerHTML = template_nav({links: navlinks});
    var bodyId = document.body.id;
});
```

What I'm trying to do exactly is that if the body id is e.g. "`contact`", I want the list element containing the link to "`#contact`" to have a class "`active`".

I can't really just search through all the "`a`" tags, because there may be more a elements with the same links and I only need to add the class to links in the "`nav`" `div`, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

Any help or links to relevant documentation would be really appreciated

Comment: Does this mean that the `id` attribute of the `body` will change at various times?  Do you have more than one `body` element?  Or is it that you are styling several pages and applying a different `id` to the `body` of each?

Comment: this script will be used by several pages each of which has a separate id for its body element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might point you into the right direction.

First, change your navbar HTML to have a class parameter

```
var navbar = "
    <div class='nav'>
        <ul class='nav'>
        {{#each links}}
            <li class={{className}}>
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                <a href='#{{link}}'>{{name}}</a>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>";
```

Then change your navlinks array to do the same

```
var navlinks = [
    {className: '', link: 'home', name: 'Home'},
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {className: '', link: 'about', name: 'About Us'},
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {className: '', link: 'contact', name: 'Contact Us'}
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
];
```

Then

```
if (bodyId === 'contact') {
    var i = 0;
    for (i; i < navlinks.length; i += 1) {
        if (navlinks[i].link === 'contact') {
            navlinks[i].className = 'active';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I went even further by coming up with a consistent naming convention where the body id would be the exact same string as the link's href (minus any extensions or prefix urls). That eliminated the need for the "if (bodyId === 'contact')" statement

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cHP2B/) that demonstrates how you could do this using Mustache's `{{#if}}` directive combined with simply enumerating over the links and comparing them to the id of the body.

**EDIT**

Code:

```
var navbar = '<div class="nav">' +
                '<ul class="nav">' +
                    '{{#each links}}' +
                        '<li>' +
                            '<a href="#{{link}}" {{#if active}}class="active"{{/if}}>{{name}}</a>' +
                        '</li>' +
                    '{{/each}}' +
                '</ul>' +
            '</div>';
var template_nav = Handlebars.compile(navbar);
var navlinks = [
    {link:"home", name:"Home"},
    {link:"about", name:"About Us"}, 
    {link:"contact", name:"Contact Us"}
];

var bodyId = document.body.id;

findActiveLink(navlinks, bodyId).active = true;
document.querySelector("#nav").innerHTML = template_nav({links: navlinks});

function findActiveLink(navlinks, identifier) {
    var active = {};
    var i;
    for (var i = 0, l = navlinks.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (navlinks[i].link === identifier) {
            active = navlinks[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    return active;
}
```